# Getting no of solutions 0 using cplex.getSolnPoolNsolns()

Tags: java, cplex

I am trying to solve a model in Cplex using Java. But when I am trying to get the no of solution in the solution pool using cplex.getSolnPoolNsolns(), it is returning the value of 0. I am wondering what does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your code matches with following standard example from the CPLEX documentation.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      if ( args.length != 1 ) {
         usage();
         return;
      }
      try {
         IloCplex cplex = new IloCplex();

         cplex.importModel(args[0]);

         /* Set the solution pool relative gap parameter to obtain solutions
            of objective value within 10% of the optimal */

         cplex.setParam(IloCplex.DoubleParam.SolnPoolGap, 0.1);

         if ( cplex.populate() ) {
            System.out.println("Solution status = " + cplex.getStatus());
            System.out.println("Incumbent objective value  = "
                               + cplex.getObjValue());             

            /* Get the number of solutions in the solution pool */

            int numsol = cplex.getSolnPoolNsolns();
            System.out.println("The solution pool contains " + numsol +
                               " solutions.");

      }
}
```

Are you missing any of the steps like `cplex.populate()`.